# Unix: How to check the existence of a tag at the beginning of each file before insertion?

Tags: unix, tags

*The question is related to [the question "Unix: Add a Tag to the beginning of each file?".](https://superuser.com/questions/36575/unix-add-a-tag-to-the-beginning-of-each-file)*

How can I put the tag only to the files that do not contain the tag, such as `<?php`,  already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
head -n1 file | grep -q "^<?php" || sed -i "1s/^/<?php /" file
```

Answer (score 2):

Suitably modified version of [my answer to the original question](https://superuser.com/questions/36575/unix-add-a-tag-to-the-beginning-of-each-file/36584#36584):

```
perl -0777 -p -i -e 's/^/<?php/g unless m/^<\?php/' testfile
```

Running this command with `-i.bak` instead of `-i` will preserve a backup of the original files with a .bak extension.

**Edit:** Updated the match from `m/<?php/` to `m/^<\?php/` to make it match only the beginning of the file, and to escape the `?` character.

Answer (score 0):

You want || (OR).  If the left hand is true, it will not bother with the right hand. e.g.

```
test "$(grep PATTERN FILE)" || sed COMMAND FILE
```

Comment: The `test $( )` part here is not needed, and even breaks the whole test. `grep -q blah ||` is enough.